# How to set field required which is comming from the parent contenttype of my custom contenttype?

Tags: content-type, inheritance

I have a custom contenttype. This contenttype is inherited some columns from the OOTB contenttype "ArticlePage". I would like to set one of these columns required in my custom contenttype. How to do that programmatically? I am talking about the column "ArticleStartDate".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SPContentType contentType = curWeb.ContentTypes["Custom CT Name"];

SPField field = contentType.Fields["ArticleStartDate"];
contentType.FieldLinks[field.Id].Required = true;
contentType.Update();
```

Use the FieldLinks property of the contenty type. There are quite a lot of examples explaining using this property.
Refer msdn as well : [FieldLinks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttype.fieldlinks.aspx)

Comment: "ArticleStartDate" is an internal name, I assume. So the code would be: contentType.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("ArticleStartDate");